# Disable SharePoint Online from sending emails during site collections migrations

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, administration, sharepoint-email, outgoing-email

I want to migrate sharepoint on-premises sites 2013 into office 365. Now inside the on-premises sites i already have some list workflows which get fired when items and created and updated. so i do not want users to receive massive emails during the migration. Now i am using a third party tool named "share-gate" to do the migration, and this tool mentioned that if we migrate the whole site collection, then list workflows will no get fired. but to be on the safe side, i want to disable sharepoint online from sending emails during the migration, and enable it once the migration is done?
now in sharepoint on-premises i usually disable sending emails by providing invalid url inside the `Central Administration` >> `Outbound SMTP server`, but i am not sure if i can do the same inside SharePoint online?
Thanks 
Thanks